# OBS: Using VLC via Window Capture to stream doesn't display the video

Tags: vlc-media-player, obs-studio

I'm trying to stream a video using VLC media on YouTube while not showing the viewers what I'm doing behind the scene on my laptop. So, I thought of using Windows Capture which is to capture by VLC window. However, when I select the vlc window, it only shows a blank screen and the VLC window shown inside OBS seems out of size. I tried in my other laptop and it works. Could it be resolution incompatibility?

Comment: I think your question should be a bit more specific on what you are trying to do and especially what have you tried to do and how did that fail. You also mention OBS and Window Capture, which seem to point to a specific software, but you also mention Window*s* Capture, which could point to a Win10 Game Bar feature.

Comment: I'm not using Game Bar. I'm using the VLC Window Capture source.